# Child component not updating view when new data is passed through @Input()

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have an Angular 5 app where I have a list of projects. A user clicks on a project and the project details are displayed in a popup. The detail view is the child component. I pass the data to the detail view via **@Input**

**Parent Component Template:**

```
 // User clicks this button to pass the "clicked upon" project to the onSelect() function.

 <a class="uk-button uk-button-default" id="edit-btn" (click)="onSelect(project)" uk-toggle="target: #project-detail">View Project Details</a>


// Nested Child Component

   <project-detail [project]="selectedProject"></project-detail>
```

**Parent Component:**

```
// The onSelect() function

onSelect(project: IProject) {
    this.selectedProject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(project));
  }
```

**Child Component:**

```
@Input() project: IProject;
```

**Child Component Template:**

```
   <div id="fullName"><h1>{{project?.firstName + " " + project?.lastName}}</h1></div>
   <div id="title"><h2>{{project?.title}}</h2></div>
   <div id="summary"><p>{{project?.summary}}</p></div>
```

**The Issue:**

**The issue only arises sometimes** but if the user select **Project A** to view its detail and then selects **Projects B** to view its detail. The details view shows **Projects A's** data. No matter what project the user clicks on the the details view will only show **Project A's** detail.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show us the part of the markup where `project` is defined? With the current code, we cannot see if the argument passed to `onSelect` is correct. Did you log the value of `project` inside of `onSelect` to see if the value is OK?

Comment: @ConnorsFan yeah I did `log` the value of `project` and it contained the correct data every time the user click on a new project. But for some reason the view won't update itself. I'll the markup in a sec.

Comment: i have another question: why are you first stringify the then parse the project? as i understand your code correct the selectedProject of the parent is already an IProject and the Input of the child is an IProject too?!

Comment: I have the same issue, did you find a solution to this problem?